# How to make RNN with same input as CNN?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I have a working cnn with text 
my X_train's shape is (39971, 10000) , y_train: (39971, 4)

```
max_words = 10000

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(max_words,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

this works so far.
 And this his is how I'm trying to make the RNN:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 128))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I can compile the model but when I try to run `model.fit` with my training data i get an error:
**ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_42 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (39971, 4)**
What does this mean? How could I fix this?

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123306/error-when-checking-model-target-expected-dense-39-to-have-3-dimensions-but-go) suggest I might need to add `input_shape` but I'm not sure with what values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LSTM layer is currently returning the full sequence, so the output of the network has shape `(batch_size, nb_timesteps, 4)`. I presume you want to use the last LSTM output only. If that's the case, set `return_sequences=False`.